# Generate a heatmap that imputes from a value of a scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, heatmap, binning

I have a pandas dataframe scatterplot of data with varying intensities (encoded in the cool to warm colors), and I wanted to convert this into a continuous binned output, similar to a heatmap.

[image: the original scatterplot]

After reading over several questions I saw most people were doing methods that involved a conversion into a density plot or a 2d-histogram, such as this code below (still using my dataframe `sim`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

def myplot(x, y, s, bins=1000):
    heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
    heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=s)

    extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
    return heatmap.T, extent

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

# Generate some test data

sigmas = [0, 16, 32, 64]

for ax, s in zip(axs.flatten(), sigmas):
    if s == 0:
        ax.scatter(sim[0], sim[1], s=10, lw=0, c=sim["Choice"],cmap='coolwarm', label='Choice')
        ax.set_title("Scatter plot")
    else:
        img, extent = myplot(sim[0], sim[1], s)
        ax.imshow(img, extent=extent, origin='lower', cmap=cm.jet)
        ax.set_title("Smoothing with  $\sigma$ = %d" % s)

plt.show()
```

[image: attempts to generate a heatmap]

or:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist2d(sim[0],sim[1],weights=sim["Choice"],bins=100,cmap="coolwarm")

plt.show()
```

[image: other attempt to create a heatmap]

**How could I instead of doing a counting/summing operation chose a different way to impute the value of each cell/region in the plot?**

In this case I want to take the mean value of nearby points (going to 0 if no points nearby), but say I wanted the mode, or the nearest neighbor value, or some function of the location in the plot with the points and the value at each point as input. How can I do such a thing?

A few lines of sample data from my `sim` dataframe:

```
        0          1         Choice
 0  -4.809010   -3.207281   0.078947
 1  4.367746    -0.207146   0.421053
 2  3.764409    4.295580    0.026316
 3  -0.748293   -1.657736   0.263158
 4  -3.867472   3.846792    0.421053
 5  4.369304    0.823736    0.105263
 6  4.181189    -0.651535   0.131579
 7  -0.748293   -1.657736   0.500000
 8  -5.766971   -0.585494   0.131579
 9  2.498427    0.322623    0.210526
10  2.626870    4.064973    0.473684
```

Comment: You could try `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to interpolate on a regular 2D grid and use `implot` to show the result.

Comment: is there anyway to specify the interpolation function to griddata, seemed to only have a limited selection

Comment: It provides typical interpolation methods: linear, nearest and cubic. Post more data and I'll give it a try.

Comment: Here you go. https://pastebin.com/rMNhuFCd

Comment: and the interpolations from griddata were pretty horrendous, nearest neighbor only split into 4 sections. Pretty sure I correctly formatted the data to match the doc example